# Я хочу защитить диапазон по дате

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Я хочу сделать таблицу где школьники могли отмечать сделали они задание или нет, но   например Школьник 1 мог поставить сделал ли он задание в столбе D только 02-09-19, а все остальные столбы были заблокированы, а с наступления 03-09-19 он мог заполнять только столб E и так до бес конечности. Также чтобы например школьник 5 мог заполнять столб D 02-09-19 и 03-09-19, а столб E 03-09-19 04-09-19 и так до без конечности. И так чтобы Школьник 1 поле моих изменений в коде получил возможности пятого и наоборот. В начале у всех кроме первого нет возможности к изменению в течении 2 дней. Простите если я много хочу. Могли бы вы рассказать как это сделать как можно подробней

Я попытался сам сделать используя это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104808/prevent-cells-from-being-edited-based-on-date-google-sheets?rq=1 но ничего не получилось.

Таблица:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ou1_FYewl2k8OW035pIp-repIflXYK8PDSszc_GPuXE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Подозреваю, что гугл-таблицы это неправильный инструмент для решения подобной задачи

Comment: Из примера выше видно, что необходимо использовать Google Apps Script. Если вы не рабираетесь в вопросе, то вам необходимо нанять специалиста.