# Я хочу защитить диапазон по дате (упрощенный)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Я хочу сделать таблицу где школьники могли отмечать сделали они задание или нет, но например Школьник 1 мог поставить сделал ли он задание в столбе D только 02-09-19, а все остальные столбы были заблокированы, а с наступления 03-09-19 он мог заполнять только столб E и так до бес конечности.

Таблица: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ou1_FYewl2k8OW035pIp-repIflXYK8PDSszc_GPuXE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Я хочу защитить диапазон по дате](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021241/%d0%af-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Официальная инструкция от Google по защите определенных ячеек или даже целых листов от редактирования со всеми подробностями:

["Как защитить, скрыть или изменить лист"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=ru).

Обратите внимание на раздел: "**Как защитить диапазон ячеек или лист**".

Comment: Там не написано как изменять с учётам даты.

Comment: Начните с малого. Может стоит как-то перестроить таблицу? Я бы порекомендовал перевернуть таблицу, чтобы даты оказались по левой стороне, так Вы сможете добавлять новые даты вниз, а сами столбцы можно закрепить за отдельными учениками и Вам не придется думать над ограничениями, так как они попросту будут постоянно распространяться вниз. Как насчет такого варианта?

Comment: Ограничения нужны для того чтобы школьники не ставили что они сделали дз в последний день, а ставили сразу.

Comment: Может есть какие-то возможности для управления областями, сдвигом ограничений, но тут у меня уже не хватает опыта. А Вы уверены, что ученики добросовестно отредактируют значение в таблице? Ученик может и не сделать домашнее задание, а сам отредактирует запись в Вашей таблице. Другой ученик не имел возможности попасть в интернет, хотя добросовестно сделал домашнее задание. Тут уже встает вопрос по поводу эффективности и практичности вашей таблицы. Может получиться так, что управление таблицей выйдет трудозатратнее (из-за издержек ведения) чем обычную книгу учителя. Может вообще не ограничивать?

Comment: Я сам ученик этого класса, а учитель у нас принципиальный так что отвертеться от создания таблицы не получиться, но всё ровно спасибо и до свидания.

Comment: Возможно стоит копать сюда: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection

Comment: И завязать на триггер по времени.